# Custom Diamention on google analytics not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

Below is the code that I use to set and id for the 'View' and another as custom diamention in my android app. Both these are implemented at the tracker level, so that with every GA call this these values are also set.

```
tracker.set("&uid", userId); //for view 
tracker.set("&CustUserID", custID); //for custom dimension
```

Now the issue is that the tracker set for view works, but for custom dimension its not working. CustUserID is the name of the dimension I have created.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your code to properly set the custom dimension with appropriate dimension index. Detailed documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets).

```
tracker.setCustomDimension(4, custId);
```

Where your custom dimension you created is indexed at 4.
But if you insist on using the [measurement protocol syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_):

```
tracker.set('&cd4', custId);
```

`CustUserID` is not in the [defined parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_) so it will not work.

Comment: I am not able to use " tracker.setCustomDimension(4, custId); ". It says the methord setCustomDimension doesnt exist.

Comment: were you able to get the `tracker.set('&cd4', custId);` to work?